# Compact submanifold has no global parametrization

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

$M \subseteq R^d $ is a compact submanifold of $R^d$ and contains at least 2 points. Show that $M$ has no global parametrization.

How can I show this?

Answer (score 0):

If it were the case, then the chart would be a homeomorphism, but the only open/compact sets in $\mathbb R^d$ are the empty set or for $d=0$ the set $\{0\}$, both in contradiction with the requirement that the submanifold has at least two points.